# Not sure how a node is passed as parameter in LinkedList instance method in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, parameters

I have started implementing linked list in python , I was able to create a traverse method and how to insert in the beginning of list method but while implementing this method of insertion of a node after a specific node , I have observed a code online that uses `prev_node` as one of the parameters including `data` , my question here is , all this time I thought only a single value parameters can be passed as param but not something that could be bundled with other attributes , for instance , `data` here is single value parameter but when it comes to `prev_node` it has `prev_node.pointer` in it and since it's a parameter we are passing , not sure how does this have a property of node which is `pointer` in this scenario? could someone please help on how is this working ? Here is the code

```
class Node():
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
        self.pointer=None
        
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
           
    
    def add_beg(self,data):
        """ add data in the beginning """
        new_node=Node(data)
        new_node.pointer=self.head
        self.head=new_node
        
    def traverse(self):
        if self.head is None:
            print('no value found ')
            return
        else:
            current=self.head
            while current is not None:
                print(current.data,'')
                current=current.pointer
                
                
    def add_after(self,prev_node,data):
        """ add data after the specific node  """
        new_node=Node(data)
        new_node.pointer=prev_node.pointer   #Here is the part I do not understand
        prev_node.pointer=new_node
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to explain with a simple example.
Given a list of data elements ['B', 'D', 'E]
let's create a Linked List consisting of Nodes each Node will be defined by 3 pieces of info as follows:

- id - just a number representing the sequence of node instantiation
- data - the data contained within the node
- prev_node - the node id of the previous node

Given this data let's build a linked list using your add method:

```
LL = LinkedList() -> LL.self.head = None    
LL.add_beg('B') -> Node(1, 'B', None), LL.self.head = 1
```

When we execute LL.add_beg('B') we create a Node instance and set LL.self.head = node Id
When we add a second data value

```
LL.add_beg('D') -> Node(2, 'D', 1), LL.self.head = 2
```

At this point we have the following:

```
LL.self.head = 2  
Node(2, 'D', 1)
Node(1, 'B', None)
```

Now let's add a Node between 2 & 1, as folows:

```
LL.add_after(2, 'E')
  new_node = Node('E') -> Node(3,'E', None)
  new_node.pointer= prev_node.pointer -> Node(3, 'E', 1)  From the prev_pointer of Node #2
  prev_node.pointer=new_node  -> Node(2, 'D', 3)  update Node #2 with new_node ID
```

The end result is a linkedList that lookslike the following:

```
LL.self.head = 2  
Node(2, 'D', 3)
Node(3, 'E', 1
Node(1, 'B', None)
```

And the new node is successfully inserted between Nodes 1 & 2.

Answer (score 0):

---

I'll just state your doubt and try to clear it

so according to me you are thinking that :
why should we point to the previous pointer ? or any other theory

solution:
so here we are trying to add a data in between that means-
the new node carrying the data should be fitted in between the prev_node and next_node

past state: head->.....prev_node->next_node->....->tail

after fitting the new node :  head->.....prev_node->new_node->next_node->....->tail

for achieving new_node->next_node syntax:
new_node.pointer=prev_node.pointer #because the pointer to the next_node is stored in prev_node in past state(***stress here***)

for achieving prev_node->new_node syntax:
prev_node.pointer=new_node #updating the prev_pointer because it is storing pointer from the past state

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).